# How to set XMP image metadata in iOS?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, metadata, exif, xmp

`CGImageProperties.h` lists a bunch of keys to specify EXIF and IPTC metadata. And I can successfully set EXIF metadata for JPEG images:

```
- (NSData*)imageDataForImage:(UIImage*)image {
    NSDictionary *metadata = @{kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary: @{(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyExifLensModel: @"my lens"}};

    NSData* rawImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0f);
    NSMutableData *imageData = [NSMutableData data];
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef) rawImageData, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)imageData, kUTTypeJPEG, 1, NULL);
    CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(destination, source, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef) metadata);
    CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
    CFRelease(source);
    CFRelease(destination);
    return imageData;
}
```

However, I'm missing how to specify XMP metadata, specifically the [XMP.GPano](http://www.exiv2.org/tags-xmp-GPano.html) keys. I tried a dictionary like this:

```
@{@"XMP": @{@"GPano": @{@"PosePitchDegrees": @20}}}
```

but it is simply ignored. Is this even possible using Core Graphics?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue, were you able to find a solution or is it simply not possible by using image destination?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMP SDK for this. It's a robust and cross-platform solution (actually used by Apple internally).